# BQL Duplicate detection

Tags: acumatica

I need to write a BQL statement to select rows from SOOrder that are duplicated by 4 key fields.  I want to select the duplicated rows for a processing page and allow the user to check the orders to delete.  I have the page and all the logic prepared. I just need the BQL query to present the duplicates.  Can someone give me a template query?  I know I will need GroupBy and Aggregate.

Comment: I have created a query that does the grouping and the count, but I have two issues.  1. I don't know how to select only those rows with a count greater than 1. 2. I don't know how to add the count value to the grid.

Comment: Here is the query:               var cmd = new PXSelectGroupBy<SOOrder, Where<SOOrderExt.usrEDICustomerId, IsNotNull>,
                Aggregate<GroupBy<SOOrderExt.usrEDICustomerId, GroupBy<SOOrderExt.usrEDICustomerVendorId,
                GroupBy<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr, GroupBy<SOOrder.customerLocationID, Count<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>>>,
                OrderBy<Asc<SOOrderExt.usrEDICustomerId, Asc<SOOrderExt.usrEDICustomerVendorId,
                Asc<SOOrder.customerOrderNbr, Asc<SOOrder.customerLocationID, Asc<SOOrder.customerRefNbr>>>>>>>(this);

Comment: you can add it as an answer and accept it, so others know you got it!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to filter values with count<2 in select delegate. 
To show count in the grid you should just specify counted field in the grid. In your case it is SOOrder.orderNbr